# How to get the source of all JButton components from an ActionEvent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a simple window that contain two buttons `Yes` and `No`.

When clicking on `Yes` I want to disable the `No` button and when pressing on `No` I want to disable the `Yes` button.

I've implemented:

```
JButton btnYes = new JButton("Yes");
contentPane.add(btnYes);
btnYes.setActionCommand("Yes");
btnYes.addActionListener(this);
```

*...the same for the `No` button...*

Now I'm catching the event in this method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Yes"))
    {
        //I know how to get the button that caused the event 
        //but I don't know how to disable the OTHER button.
        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
        //Handle the source button...
    }

}
```

In the above method I have an access to the button that caused the event, but not to the other button.

What is the best way of getting the buttons?

Comment: Use a `JCheckBox` or `JToggleButon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just implement ActionListener as a nested class of your Dialog's class, in this case you will have full access to all fields of outer class (in which you should store reference to buttons when your create them).

The bad dirty solution (that should NOT be used) still exists:  to navigate to battens through getParent() of JButton and then through getChildren() of parents childrens. Just to show that it is possible anyway.

Comment: But then I have to change the buttons to `final` don't I?

Comment: @MarounMaroun No you don't, if you store buttons as dialog class fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `JButton` array as class member variable and to check which instance *didnt* cause the event:

```
for (JButton button: buttonArray) {
   if (button != source) {
      button.setEnabled(false); // disable the other button
   }
}
```

Comment: IMHO it is a good design. The array doesn't have to be a class member variable of your main class. It can be a member variable of an [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) class for instance. This would be a single class dedicated to managing the interaction between the buttons.